# error while launching eclipse RCP application with latest plugins ( Eclipse 4.8 )

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to migrate eclipse RCP application ( Eclipse 3.7 to Eclipse 4.8). I copied all the latest required plugins from Eclipse 4.8 and updated our RCP plugins.

**Could someone help me in understanding what all needs to be modified apart from updating the required plugins to latest version ( in my case , to Eclipse photon 4.8)**

I am facing an error when i try to launch the application by using the existing config.ini file with the latest set of plugins in my plugins folder

**PS : i am able to launch the application from the Eclipse Via Run configuration**

I am getting an error when i try to launch the rcp application using the exisiting *.exe and config.ini files Error is displayed as "**Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).**"

In `Config.ini` , the `osgi.bundles` value is specified as **osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.core.runtime@start,\ org.eclipse.equinox.common@start,\ org.eclipse.update.configurator,\ org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86**

Below is the detailed error log , `javax.inject` and `org.eclipse.core.jobs` relevant version jars are available in the plugin folder but still i am getting this error , any clue what could be the cause?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2018-09-07 11:26:32.798
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-09-07 11:26:32.807
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.14.0.v20180417-0825.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86 2 0 2018-09-07 11:26:32.811
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86 [4]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher; bundle-version="[1.0.0,1.6.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher; bundle-version="[1.0.0,1.6.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2018-09-07 11:26:32.812
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-09-07 11:26:32.815
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
```

Answer (score 0):

That `osgi.bundles` doesn't look right as it is only starting two plugins.

If you are using a `xxx.product` file to configure the RCP select the 'generate a default config.ini' option on the 'Configuration' tab to get Eclipse PDE to build the config.ini for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , When i try to generate a configuration from xxx.product , i get the following entry for osgi.bundles,    "osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator@1:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info" .      I was wondering whether we have any other ways to load RCP application instead of using simpleconfigurator and specifying the bundles.info , can't we use

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect. The build should generate a `bundles.info` file in the `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` directory (in the configuration directory) listing all the plugins to be loaded. You must make sure the xxx.product file lists **all** the required plugins

Comment: Thanks Greg, I understand that by listing the bundles.info in the simpleconfigurator directory,  we can load all the listed plugins and launch application. I am looking at a way where in I can load all the plugins which are available in plugin folder without specifying bundles.info , We were able to achieve this in earlier (i.e. with eclipse 3.7)  , now with eclipse 4.8  - i want to use the similar configuration file (I agree that one way is to use simpleconfigurator  and bundles.info ).I am looking for some other alternatives or infact use the existing  configuration setup .Any suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about that area of Eclipse.